# Manually Send Ajax request to a PHP file

Tags: javascript, ajax

It seems that the Drupal Ajax  API are comming a little un handy for my current project so i was trying to do the ajax request the good old way with actual Javascript.

I have this code

```
valdBut.click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

            jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: grabValue(),
            url: urkl,
            success: function () {

                alert(back)

            }
        });
    alert(grabValue())

})
```

What i am wondering is how should i link that URL value to my module page, so that my user_login hook receive the data sent via Ajax ?

Thanks for any help, 
Manu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial (tough Drupal 6) helped me a lot http://viziontech.co.il/tutorial1?1309179897 .

The big piece that i was missing is that i needed a Hook_menu that countain my php script that will handle the ajax request, then in the ajax path i add the newly created link (from the Hook_menu).

Also the JS needed to be added to that specific module with a drupal_add_js for the ajax call back to be received. It took me a while to figure out but if i add the script via Theme.info file it behaves very oddly..

Answer (score 2):

For most functionality that you require with drupal, there is typically a module that already does what you are after or close to it.

I would recommend either:

- using the module http://drupal.org/project/ajax_register
- or looking at the code for the above module and make one that suits your exact needs

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for you answer, unfortunately it's not really help full in my case.

Comment: Then may I suggest you clarify your question? I read it like you are after a solution to allow users to login via AJAX on your site, is this not the case?

Comment: Yes it is but i am using Drupal 7 and the module you suggested is Drupal 6 only. It s ok i got it figured out. See answer below.